# Android App: Nothing was installed

Tags: android, installation

I did a lot of searching, but couldn't find a solution for my problem. I have a complete Android app which runs perfectly in the emulator. The signing process works fine, but as I copy the .apk-file on my phone and try to install it, it says, that nothing was installed.

Installing the app via eclipse and a USB cable works, but I can't share the app that way.

Additionally unknown sources for apps are accepted.

Do you have any idea? I'm quite embarassed, that I have to ask this here, but I don't see another way...

Comment: did you try by adb install command? Check if any error is thrown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have previously debug signed application installed. Then you need to uninstall the app first. Open terminal and type `adb uninstall <your app package name>`

Comment: This sounds like the right answer.  You could also make sure to  uninstall the existing version from the phone using the settings menu.

Comment: I was going to write down that too. But thought he has a device, he should know. :)